# Is it possible for a web page to prevent windows going into sleep mode while that page is open?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, icecast

I'm running an internet radio station that's designed to be left on in the background of shops and retail premises without anyone manning the PC. The issue I'm facing when running tests is that the computer goes into sleep mode from lack of activity and shuts the audio off. I know this option can be shut off on the PC itself, but I'm wondering if there's anything I can do that would streamline the experience for users?

Comment: What operating system and browser?  Chrome on Windows will prevent sleep (unless the battery is dead) if media is playing.  I suspect most any other browser will too.

Comment: Chrome on Windows is my primary aim. I'm playing the audio via Icecast stream through an HTML5 player and windows is going into sleep mode while it plays.

Comment: Hmm... it shouldn't be doing that.  Can you provide a code sample so we can see what exactly is going on?  This isn't autoplay by chance, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can open https://nosleep.page/ in a web browser on the PC.

> This tiny site uses the [Screen Wake Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Wake_Lock_API) to prevent your device from sleeping.
>
> Where this API isn't supported, an empty silent video is played to emulate this behaviour (using [NoSleep.js](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js)).